# How to Clone s3 bucket from one region to another using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have s3  bucket "bucket1" in Singapore region which has lifecycle policy and encryption and access policy now i want to create bucket in another region with same config as bucket1 and i want to name new bucket as prefix-bucket1.

Can someone suggest how can i do this using terraform?

Comment: Do you need to clone the bucket content also?

Comment: Did you create the initial bucket via Terraform? If so you should already have the Terraform code for the bucket and can just provide a different region (and name as bucket names are globally unique) and it should work. If it doesn't it would be helpful if you edited your question to show exactly what you tried (ideally as a [mcve]) and what error you got.

Comment: i want to copy all settings of bucket1 eg lifecycle acl and encryption setting. i have created bucket 1 manually so i dont have code

Comment: yes simply i need same bucket1 with different name and in different region with same content

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to clone the bucket then you need two providers, each for region.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
  alias = "eu-west-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
  alias = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "eu-west-1-bucket" {
  bucket = "bucket1"
  acl    = "private"
  ...
  providers = {
  aws = aws.eu-west-1
  }

}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "eu-west-2-bucket" {
   bucket = "prefix-bucket1"
   acl    = "private"
   ...
   providers = {
   aws = aws.eu-west-2
   }
        
 }
```

You need to name your providers using `alias` keyword, and use the correct provider in the resource block.

Comment: I think the OP is after "cloning" all the settings from  one bucket to new bucket one, not just copping and pasting them?

Comment: yes i want to copy all settings of bucket1 eg lifecycle acl and encryption setting. i have created bucket 1 manually so i dont have code for that .

Comment: @kunalborse Did you try `terraform import`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Terraform import the first bucket
2. Create the second bucket using terraform
3. Enable replication from the first bucket to the new bucket using [aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_replication_configuration) resource.

This will copy all the existing and new objects from the first bucket to your new bucket. You can read more about s3 replication [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/replicating-existing-objects-between-s3-buckets/)